# Почему не срабатывает логическое "или"

Tags: python, сравнение

```
def main_data():
    archive_file = input("\nВведите адрес архива ")
    # делаем проверку расширения файла
    if archive_file.endswith('.zip') or archive_file.endswith('.rar') == False:
        print(" Вы указали неверный файл. Файл не имеет расширения 'zip' или 'rar' ")
```

Comment: Не срабатывает на каких значениях? Сейчас записанное вами условие будет выполняться, если расширение zip или не rar — то есть любое кроме rar

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы были разрешены только zip и rar, значит так и нужно записать проверку на отсутствие обоих расширений `if not archive_file.endswith('.zip') and not archive_file.endswith('.rar'):`

Comment: Расставьте скобки в выражении. Сайчас оно вычислдяется как `archive_file.endswith('.zip') or ( archive_file.endswith('.rar') == False )`.

Comment: А, возможно, ещё лучше (но это не точно) `if os.path.splitext(archive_file)[1].lower() not in ('.zip', '.rar'):`

Comment: Если вы не уверены, и у вас подряд несколько условий , то записывайте их в скобки по приоритетам. потому что текущее ваше условие на самом деле выглядит так: `if archive_file.endswith('.zip') or (archive_file.endswith('.rar') == False)`. То есть, в правой части сначала сравнивается значение с False, а потом выполняется логическое "или".

Comment: Да вообще обычно сравнения с `False` (да и с `True`) излишни. `if x == False` -> `if not x`

Comment: А вообще тут можно ещё так по продвинутому: `if not any(map(archive_file.endswith, ('.zip', '.rar'))):`

Comment: Или так: `not list(filter(lambda el: archive_file.endswith(el), ('.zip', '.rar')))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У Вас на данном этапе проверяется, что название либо заканчивается на '.zip', либо не заканчивается на '.rar', т.е. оно верно для любых файлов, кроме '.rar'. Вы судя про всему хотели, чтобы проверка была успешной, если расширение файла не совпадает ни с одним из этих случаев. В таком случае нужно либо обе проверки взять в скобки, либо проверять каждую на соответствие условию.
2. Проверять на `... == False` не принято, правильнее проверять `not ...`
3. Для Вашего случая все вообще просто, т.к. метод `endswith` может принимать кортеж в качестве аргумента.

```
def main_data():
    archive_file = input("\nВведите адрес архива ")
    # делаем проверку расширения файла
    if not archive_file.endswith(('.zip', '.rar')):
        print(" Вы указали неверный файл. Файл не имеет расширения 'zip' или 'rar' ")
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def main_data():
    archive_file = input('Введите адрес архива: ')
    if not archive_file.endswith('.zip') and not archive_file.endswith('.rar'):
        print('Вы указали неверный файл. Файл не имеет расширения \'.zip\' или \'.rar\'.')
```